# How does the frightful aspect spell give the shaken and frightened condition?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, fear

[Frightful aspect](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/frightful-aspect/) is a 8th level spell :

> You also emit an aura that emanates 30 feet from you. Enemy creatures
>   within the aura are shaken. Each time a creature shaken by this aura
>   hits you with a melee attack, that creature becomes frightened for 1d4
>   rounds, though at the end of that duration it is no longer affected by
>   this aura. The aura’s effect is a fear and mind-affecting effect.

It doesn't say you can make a save to avoid either conditions.

**There is no possible save ? Or does it work like the *frightfull presence* aura ?**

> ***Frightful Presence*** (Ex) This special quality makes a creature’s very
>   presence unsettling to foes. Activating this ability is a free action
>   that is usually part of an attack or charge. Opponents within range
>   who witness the action may become frightened or shaken. The range is
>   usually 30 feet, and the duration is usually 5d6 rounds. This ability
>   affects only opponents with fewer Hit Dice than the creature has. An
>   opponent can resist the effects with a successful Will save (DC 10 +
>   1/2 the frightful creature’s racial HD + the frightful creature’s Cha
>   modifier; the exact DC is given in the creature’s descriptive text).
>   An opponent that succeeds on the saving throw is immune to that same
>   creature’s frightful presence for 24 hours. On a failed save, the
>   opponent is shaken, or panicked if it has 4 Hit Dice or fewer.
>   Frightful presence is a mind-affecting fear effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**There is no save, it always works**

Since the spell doesn't mention a saving throw, creatures affected don't get one. They are automatically shaken/frightened unless they are immune to such conditions.

In general, spells either use an attack roll or a save, and if they don't use either then the effect is minimal. In this case you are using a level 8 spellslot to give a -2 to attack rolls, saving throws, and some other stuff. Compared to other level 8 spells (Like Fire Storm or Anti-Magic field) this is not very significant, and most of the value of Frightful Aspect comes from the bonus to Strength and the DR and SR.